# Sound Recorder in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, audio-player

I am developing a midlet application for recording in .wav format.
I use Nokia SDK 6th edition.
I tried with Player using following code.

`p = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?enc=audio/wav");`

Its recorded successfully and save test.amr in memory card..But we see details in mobile it shows the .amr format.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it does not recognize that `?enc=audio/wav`. According to the [MMAPI specification](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/index.html), wav is `audio/x-wav`.
The whole sencente would be like

```
Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=audio/x-wav");
```

Does that work?

Comment: ya i created like that only... but it is in .wav format....It is in .amr format...........

Comment: @user521225 Did you notice the difference? I mean, according to your question you created it in a different way, the String is slightly different.